# uploading and showing the thumbnail of a video

Tags: php, video, upload, video-streaming, mime

hello all i am working for my company and the company wants me to build a video sharing site i have  made all the basic functionality and interface but now i am having issue with uploading videos to the site and showing the thumbnail after upload please help me by suggesting some plugins or any kind of help is very important.

i am uploading the videos by the following code

```
 var progressbarhead     = $('#progressbarhead');
var statustxthead       = $('#statustxthead');
 $(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
        target:   '#output909090jk',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        uploadProgress: OnProgresshead,
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
    }; 

 $('#thef_op90op').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 
    }); 
     function OnProgresshead(event, position, total, percentComplete)
   {
//Progress bar
progressbarhead.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
statustxthead.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
 }
   //function to check file size before uploading.
  function beforeSubmit(){
//check whether browser fully supports all File API
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {

      if( !$('#file09_09o9').val()) //check empty input filed
    {
        $("#output").html("Please choose a image for your ad - camera button     above this message.");
        return false
    }

    var fsize = $('#file09_09o9')[0].files[0].size; //get file size
    var ftype = $('#file09_09o9')[0].files[0].type; // get file type


    //allow only valid image file types 
    switch(ftype)
    {
        case 'image/png': case 'image/gif': case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
            break;
        default:
            $("#output").html("<b>"+ftype+"</b> Unsupported file type!");
            return false
    }

    //Allowed file size is less than 1 MB (1048576)
    if(fsize>3048576) 
    {
        $("#output").html("<b>"+bytesToSize(fsize) +"</b> Too big Image file! <br />Please reduce the size of your photo using an image editor.");
        return false
    }

    $("#output").html("");  
}
else
{
    //Output error to older unsupported browsers that doesn't support HTML5 File API
    $("#output").html("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
    return false;
}
}
```

html is here

```
 <input type="file" name="profileimage99" style="display:nonle;" onchange="$('#ok_po90klk').click();" id="file09_09o9">
                        <input type="submit" name="filesubmited" value="upload" id="ok_po90klk" class="the_SUb_mit_Upload6"/>
```

also suggest me any mime types for video.

Comment: I think you're getting down-votes because you keep asking for suggestions to solutions but in a way that your wording makes it sound like we should be doing all the work for you.. I mean how difficult to google search for "**supported browser video mime types**"? If you want an answer follow the next suggestions below:

Comment: Edit your question with more useful details. What video format is being uploaded? How can I reproduce your problem on my computer using your shown code? Where is the thumbnail coming from? If user selected image then have you practiced using php to upload the file to a server? The uploaded file URL would then be noted and later use php to create and store some html file that has URL to uploaded image as thumbnail

Comment: thankyou sir it means a lot to me .. :) i will do what u suggested